# Trying to set up a loading screen for my game server

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, game-development

I'm trying to set up a custom loading screen with music for my Garry's Mod server. Although I'm having a really big issue. Whenever I input the youtube link embed it adds about 16 pixels to the top margin of the screen, causing a large whitespace to appear. The youtube embed is set to be 0x0 px so I can't figure any of this out, I've spent a few hours today looking at the code(most of it was made open source by another user, I'm just modifying), and I can't find anything. Please help!I'd also like to ask if anyone knows how to control the default volume of the video when it auto-plays, I feel it's a bit too loud. Here is a link to the actual loading screen that we will be using(Not finished yet, just want to sort out the margin error before changing more stuff): http://lawsofdestruction.nn.pe.loading.lawsofdestruction.nn.pe/LoadingScreen/

And here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--    
    AUTHOR: Xonos
    STEAM NAME: frag51richardo
    I hope you like it! :)
    -->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Loading</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Parallax HTML One-Page Template for Agency and Personal">
    <meta name="author" content="The Develovers">

    <!-- Styles 
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
        font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    --> 
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Pacifico|Kaushan+Script|PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--<link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="assets/css/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/global-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        td {
            padding:5px!important;
            color:#FFF;
        } 
        .no-padding {
            padding:0px!important;
        }
        .no-margin {
            margin:0px!important;
        }
        .workshopItemPreviewImage {
            max-width:100%;
            text-align: right;
            border:2px solid #FFF;
        }
        .workshopItemTitle {
            color:#FFF!important;
            font-size:15pt!important;
            text-align:left;
            font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
            margin-bottom:0px!important;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        .workshopItemShortDesc {
            display:none;
        }
        .fileRating {
            display:none;
        }
        .workshopItemAuthor {
            padding-left:10px!important;
            color:#fff!important;
        }
        .workshopItemAuthorName {
            color:#fff!important;
        }
        .workshopItemAuthorName a {
            background-color:#fff!important;
            border-radius:5px!important;
            padding-left:3px!important;
            padding-right:3px!important;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        .workshopItemAuthor, workshopItemAuthorName, workshopItemAuthorName a {
            font-size:10pt!important;
            text-align:left;
            font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        .circular img {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 75px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
            -moz-border-radius: 75px;
            /*background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;*/
        }
        .text-white {
            color:#FFF;
        }
        .hdr, .hdr span {
            font-family: 'Lobster', cursive!important;
            font-size: 22pt;
        }
        .hdr2, .hdr2 span {
            font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
            font-size: 18pt!important;
        }
        .hdl {
            font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
            font-size: 16pt!important;
        }
        .reg tr td {
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        .text-left {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .txt-shadow, .txt-shadow span, .txt-shadow i, .txt-shadow strong, .txt-shadow p {
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        .infobox {
            background: rgba(144,144,144,0.4);    /* 40% opaque red */  
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
            -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
            box-shadow:         inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .margintop {
            margin-top: 24px;
        }

        .loadbarfx {
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
            -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
            box-shadow:         inset 0px 1px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="top" class="no-margin no-padding margintop" >
    <object style="height: 0px; width:0px;">
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/0O-QKo2SIuU?version=3&autoplay=1&loop=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowScriptAccess="always" width="0" height="0">
    </object>
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <?php//$videolink = '0O-QKo2SIuU&t'; ?>
    <!--<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php //echo $videolink; ?>?autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=<?php //echo $videolink; ?>"></iframe>-->
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="./assets/wallpapers/module.wallpapers.php"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:0;position:absolute;overflow:hidden!important;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <img src="logo.png" style="max-width:30%;"/></br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 infobox">
        <table style="width:100%;" class="reg">
            <tr><td colspan=2 class="text-center hdr"><i class="fa fa-legal" style="color:#D31E1B;"></i> How to get Banned<td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i></td><td>Prop Pushing & Spamming</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i></td><td>Committing Douche Baggery</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-university"></i></td><td>Bothering Players</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-microphone-slash"></i></td><td>Mic Spamming</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></td><td>Annoying or Lag Inducing Builds</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i></td><td>Any form of Abuse</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-meh-o"></i></td><td>Lacking of Common Sense</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i></td><td>Crashing Server on Purpose</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan=2 class="text-white text-center hdr"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color:#24AA22;"></i> Acceptable<td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-bullseye"></i></td><td>PVP</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-mars-double"></i></td><td>Adult Content</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan=2 class="text-white text-center hdr"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:#225FAA;"></i> Encouraged<td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></td><td>Wiremod/ACF Builds</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-code"></i></td><td>Impressive & Original E2</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></td><td>Assistance in Finding Addon Bugs</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></td><td>Teaching Wiremod & Expression 2</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table style="width:100%;" class="reg">
                <tr><td class="text-white hdr"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#D12112!important;"></i> Server Location: <span style="color:#1F6FD1!important;">Houston, TX</span></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="text-white hdl" colspan=2>Note: Equipping a weapon removes god-mode and enables pvp. You must die to re-gain godmode.</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-white" colspan=2>
                        <p><strong><u>Updates</u>:</strong></p>
                        <p>Added Sub-Material Tool for new feature added in March Update.</p>
                        <p>SCARS is currently disabled until the author fixes it (it's causing constant server crashes</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12 infobox">
            <table style="width:100%;" class="reg">
                <tr><td colspan=3 class="text-white text-center hdr"><i class="fa fa-cubes text-primary"></i> Server Operators<td></tr>
                <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><img style="width:15px!important;height:15px!important;" src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/341/1/2/simple_crown_bullet_by_slush_bee-d892v68.png"</td><td>TheIpodk9</td><td>Owner</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><img style="width:15px!important;height:15px!important;" src="https://forums.alliedmods.net/images/smilies/bee.png"></img></td><td>Developer</td><td>Cluelesshobo</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><img style="width:15px!important;height:15px!important;" src="http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2015/059/b/1/penis_pixel_by_gaaddammit-d8jwkyb.png"></img></td><td>Mortimer McMire</td><td>Munch Blocker</td></tr>
                <tr><td class="text-white text-center"><img style="width:15px!important;height:15px!important;" src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120430113153/clubpenguin/images/b/bb/Moderator_badge_15px.png"></img></td><td><em>❈</em>AG<em>❈</em>Tjroehr</td><td>Super Admin</td></tr>
            </table>
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="border-top:1px dotted #CCC;">
                <span class="hdr2 text-white txt-shadow"><i class="fa fa-download" style="color:#FFF!important;"></i> <span id="loadingHdr" style="color:#FFF!important;">Validating Workshop Collection ...</span></span>
                <div class="progress progress-sm progress-striped active">
                    <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped txt-shadow" style="width: 0%"></div>
                </div>
                <span id="subtext1" class="text-white" style="color:#FFF!important;"></span>
                <span id="subtext2" class="text-white" style="color:#FFF!important;"></span>
                <span id="subtext3" class="text-white" style="color:#FFF!important;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 infobox" style="margin-top:10px!important;">
            <p class="text-white hdr txt-shadow" style="padding:5px;"><i class="fa fa-user-secret" style="color:#F4CB13!important;"></i> How to become an Admin</p>
            <span class="text-white txt-shadow" style="padding:5px;">Help Xonos find & resolve bugs in addons that can potentially crash the server. You must be mature and willing to help manage the server with a willingness to help with management in general. Typically there is an age requirement of 17+. <strong>No "<i>Can I haz adminz plzzz</i>"</strong>.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 infobox" style="margin-top:15px!important;">
            <p class="text-white hdr txt-shadow" style="padding:15px!important;"><i class="fa fa-flask" style="color:#AD4CF7!important;"></i> About The Server</p>
            <span class="text-white txt-shadow" style="padding:15px!important;">This server is all about building and it is recommended that you constantly back up your builds. Gmod tends to crash and so do servers with many addons. We tend to focus more on wiremod builds however you are encouraged to build whatever it is that you want. If there are limitations that you need lifted, ask an admin and they can raise these limits for you.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        var totalfilez
        //Gets initial total files needed.
        function SetFilesTotal(total) {
            totalfilez = total;
            window.totalfiles = total;
            $('#subtext3').empty().append(total+' files found.');
        }
        //Update Progress Bar
        function SetFilesNeeded(needed) {
            window.filesleft = needed;
            $('#subtext2').empty().append(needed+' files needed.');
            if(needed < 1) {
                var neededz = window.totalfiles;
            } else {
                var neededz = needed;
            }
            var percent = Math.ceil((((window.totalfiles-neededz)/2)/(window.totalfiles/2))*100);
            if(!isNan(percent)) {
                $('#progressbar').css({ "width" : percent+"%"});
                $('#progressbar').empty().append(percent+"%");
            }
        }
        //Update loading header text.
        function SetStatusChanged( status ) {
            $('#loadingHdr').empty().append(status);
            /*
            Retrieving server info...
            Getting addon info for #------
            Found '--'
            Mounting Addons
            Workshop Complete
            Sending client info...
            */
            if(status == 'Retrieving server info...') {
                $('#progressbar').css({ "width" : "10%"});
                $('#progressbar').empty().append("Initializing ...");
            }
            if(status == 'Mounting Addons') {
                $('#progressbar').css({ "width" : "55%"});
                $('#progressbar').empty().append("55%");
            }
            if(status == 'Workshop Complete') {
                $('#progressbar').css({ "width" : "89%"});
                $('#progressbar').empty().append("89%");
            }
            if(status == 'Sending client info...') {
                $('#progressbar').css({"width" : "100%"}, 15000);
                $('#progressbar').empty().append('Finalizing ...');
            }
        }
        //Downloading file event.
        function DownloadingFile(fileName) {
            $('#subtext1').empty().append('Obtaining '+fileName+'.</br><b>'+window.filesleft+'</b> out of <b>'+window.totalfiles+'</b>');
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Server Workshop Collection -->
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute!important;bottom:25px;">
        <?php
        include 'simple_html_dom.php';
        $url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?&format=json&id=124102726';
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        foreach($html->find('.collectionItem') as $element) {
            $workshop .= '<div class="workshopAddon col-xs-4 text-center no-padding" style="display:none;">';

            foreach($element->find('.workshopItemPreviewHolder') as $previewImg) {
                $img = '<div class="col-xs-3 no-padding text-center circular">'.$previewImg->innertext.'</div>';
            }

            foreach($element->find('.workshopItemTitle') as $displayName) {
                $title = '<p class="workshopItemTitle">'.$displayName->innertext.'</p>';
            }

            foreach($element->find('.workshopItemAuthor') as $displayName) {
                $author = '<p class="workshopItemAuthor">'.$displayName->innertext.'</p>';
            }


            $workshop .= $img.'
                <div class="col-xs-9 no-padding">
                '.$title.$author.'
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        echo $workshop;
        ?>
        <script>
                var animationIn = 'fadeIn';
                var animationOut = 'fadeOut';
                var interval = 1500;
                var pass = 1;
                $('.workshopAddon').sort(function(){
                    return (Math.round( Math.random() ) - 0.5 );
                }).each(function() {
                    var e = $(this)
                    setTimeout(function() { e.show("fast").addClass('animated '+animationIn); }, interval);
                    setTimeout(function() { e.removeClass(animationIn).addClass(animationOut).delay(2000).hide("fast"); }, (interval+6000));
                    if(pass <= 2) {
                        interval = interval+1000;
                    } else {
                        pass = 0;
                        interval = interval+9000;
                    }
                    pass = pass+1;
                });

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has it's own embed for youtube, Use this format                     <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

Comment: @mlegg Sorry, I'm still a bit new to this, where do I put that in the code? And thanks so much for the help. If you ever want to check out the server check our forums out at Lawsofdestruction.nn.pe

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<object width= "0" height="0"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/https://youtu.be/0O-QKo2SIuU&theme=light&loop=1&autohide=1&playlist=https://youtu.be/0O-QKo2SIuU"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/https://youtu.be/0O-QKo2SIuU&theme=light&loop=1&autohide=1&playlist=https://youtu.be/0O-QKo2SIuU" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="0" height="0" allowscriptaccess="always"></embed></object>
```